# Where did Toa Lhikan get the Toa stones from?

Tags: bionicle

In the 2004 Bionicle lore and [movie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bionicle_2%3a_Legends_of_Metru_Nui), six matoran (Vakama, Nokama, Matau, Onewa, Whenua, and Nuju) are given Toa stones by Toa Lhikan. They take these Toa stones to the Great Temple in Ga-Metru, where they are changed into Toa.

Where did Toa Lhikan get the Toa stones? Did he make them himself, or did he find them somewhere? (Or were they given to him?) If Toa Lhikan did not make the Toa stones, who did?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Toa Lhikan](http://bionicle.wikia.com/wiki/Toa_Lhikan) made them.

From the [Bionicle wiki](http://bionicle.wikia.com):

> [Toa Stones](http://bionicle.wikia.com/wiki/Toa_Stone) are normal stones that a [Toa](http://bionicle.wikia.com/wiki/Toa) has given an amount of their [Toa Energy](http://bionicle.wikia.com/wiki/Toa_Energy) (not to be confused with [elemental energy](http://bionicle.wikia.com/wiki/Elements)) into. When activated on a [Suva](http://bionicle.wikia.com/wiki/Suva), a destined [Matoran](http://bionicle.wikia.com/wiki/Matoran) will become a [Toa](http://bionicle.wikia.com/wiki/Toa) and the [Toa](http://bionicle.wikia.com/wiki/Toa) whose energy was in the stone becomes a [Turaga](http://bionicle.wikia.com/wiki/Turaga).

Additionally:

> - A [Toa](http://bionicle.wikia.com/wiki/Toa) can only make 6 stones.
> - Even if a [Toa](http://bionicle.wikia.com/wiki/Toa) put all their power in [Toa Stones](http://bionicle.wikia.com/wiki/Toa_Stone), they would not become [Turaga](http://bionicle.wikia.com/wiki/Turaga) until the stone was used.